# Android - can not get resources from XML

Tags: android, xml

Android  - get resources from `XML`

Hi,

I am developing an android app for a quiz game, the game has 24 questions, and each question has a `String`(question) and four ImageButton`(answer), when user select the correct`ImageButton`, then they go to next question.

But the problem is, after selecting the first correct answer, the screen refreshes with a new question and a new set of images, but it freezes there, and no matter what I click, it will not go to next question. I have attached my code and any help appreciated!!

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game);

// set variables
int fourImageId[] = { R.id.1_4a, R.id.1_4b,R.id.1_4c, R.id.1_4d };
questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question1);
questionList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.question);
correctAnswerIdList = ListOfImages.getListOfCorrectImages();
imageIdList = ListOfImages.getListOfImages(); //two dimension array

// give values to four image buttons
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    fourImages[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(fourImageId[i]);
    final int temp = fourImageId[i];
    fourImages[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override               
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (temp==correctAnswerIdList[index]){
                questionText.setText(questionList[index]);
                for (int i = 0; i < imageIdList[index].length; i++) {
                    fourImages[i].setImageResource(imageIdList[index][i]);}
            index++;
        }
    }
});}
```

Comment: Is there anything useful in the logcat?

Answer (score 1):

Your temp variable never changes after all the button click listeners are set. Because of this, the `if (temp==correctAnswerIdList[index])` statement will only successfully execute once.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I can now understand where the problem is, should i move temp to somewhere else?

Comment: temp probably needs to be updated to a different index of `fourImageId` inside the `if` block of your `onClick` method. If the `questionList[]` and `fourImageId[]` indexes are aligned, you could probably just add a line: `temp = fourImageId[index]` right after setting `questionText`.

Answer (score 0):

Your for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) statement needs to execute once for each new question. Right now it only executes once, sets up the new question and image buttons, but your app doesn't know where to go from there.